# How can I assign an object to another object when I only have a reference to it in Java?

Tags: java, list, variable-assignment

I am using Java and have various objects that I make a list of like this:

```
objx   o1;
objx   o2;
objx   o3;

objx olist [] = { o1, o2, o3 };
```

now I want to assign other objects to the original objects o1-o3 but using the list.

Something like:

```
olist[0] = onew;
```

But in this case only the list gets changed, not the original object o1. How can I do this in Java ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this just a rehersal project or some real life scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. However you could just store the array and then you would be able to change the object referenced at each location of the array.

E.g.

```
objx olist[] = new objx[ 3 ];

olist[ 0 ] = new objx( );
olist[ 1 ] = new objx( );
olist[ 2 ] = new objx( );
```

Then later you could change any of the objects referenced simply by indexing the array:

```
...

olist[ 1 ] = onew;
```

Comment: That looks good and is easy to implement in my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

you can't. `o1` is only a reference to some address in your heap, if you assign `o1` another value, it just points to some other address.

if you need to change the "content" of the object `o1` points to, you'll have to change (probably via setters) the values of its attributes.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use container objects. I.e. an object that contains a reference to a "objx" object. The simplest container object would be an array of one element, but it is an extremely ugly and error prone solution.

Note that I have omitted accessor methods for brevity. You should not usually use direct member access like I do here.

```
public class ObjxContainer {
    public Objx objx;
}

...

ObjxContainer o1;
ObjxContainer o2;
ObjxContainer o3;
ObjxContainer[] arr = new ObjxContainer[] { o1, o2, o3 };
```

Now, accessing the objx in ObjxContainer will have the effect you want:

```
arr[0].objx = new Objx();
```